# Correct syntax to access a template function

Tags: c++11, clang

A class MessageBase has a public template member function like this:

```
/*! Get a pointer to a field. Inplace, 0 copy.
        \tparam T type of field to get
        \return pointer to field or 0 if not present */
    template<typename T>
    const T *get() const
    {
            Fields::const_iterator fitr(_fields.find(T::get_field_id()));
            return fitr == _fields.end() ? 0 : &fitr->second->from<T>();
    }
```

When I declare a pointer to a type T (in this case TEX::MDEntryPx)

```
const TEX::MDEntryPx *price = me->get();
```

then try to access the function, clang++ come back with

```
main.cpp|338|error: no matching member function for call to 'get'
```

I am not using the correct syntax but not sure what it is?

Comment: What is the declaration of `me`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh,

```
const TEX::MDEntryPx *price = me->get<TEX::MDEntryPx>();
```